# Dynamic pivot table with multiple columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic, pivot-table

I am trying to pivot table DYNAMICALLY but couldn't get the desired result.
Here is the code to create a table

```
 create table Report
 (
 deck char(3),
 Jib_in float,
 rev int,
 rev_insight int,
 jib_out float,
 creation int
 )

 insert into Report  values
 ('A_1',0.345,0,0,1.23,20140212),
 ('B_2',0.456,0,4,2.34,20140215),
 ('C_3',0.554,0,6,0.45,20140217),
 ('D_4',0.231,0,8,7.98,20140222),
 ('E_5',0.453,0,0,5.67,20140219),
 ('F_6',0.344,0,3,7.23,20140223)'
```

Code written so far.... this pivots the column deck and jib_in into rows but thats it only TWO ROWS i.e the one i put inside aggregate function under PIVOT function and one i put inside QUOTENAME()

```
 DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
 SET @columns = N'';
 SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(deck)
 FROM (SELECT p.deck FROM dbo.report AS p
 GROUP BY p.deck) AS x;
 SET @sql = N'
 SELECT ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
 FROM
 (
 SELECT p.deck, p.jib_in
 FROM dbo.report AS p
 ) AS j
 PIVOT
 (
 SUM(jib_in) FOR deck IN ('
 + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
 + ')
 ) AS p;';
 PRINT @sql;
 EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

I need all the columns to be pivoted and show on the pivoted table. any help would be appreciated. I am very new at dynamic pivot. I tried so many ways to add other columns but no avail!!
I know there are other ways please feel free to mention if there is any other way to get this right.

Comment: Kindly show the output which u want

Comment: There is a great answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320447/pivot-dynamically-returned-results-from-join-of-two-tables/21320742#21320742

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this (If you are getting Collation issue, please change all the 3 INT datatypes):

STATIC code:

```
SELECT HEADER, [A_1],[B_2],[C_3],[D_4],[E_5],[F_6]        
FROM    
(SELECT DECK,HEADER, VALUE FROM REPORT   
    UNPIVOT      
    ( 
    VALUE FOR HEADER IN ([JIB_IN],[REV],[REV_INSIGHT],[JIB_OUT],[CREATION])  
    ) UNPIV
) SRC     
PIVOT    
(
    SUM(VALUE) 
    FOR DECK IN ([A_1],[B_2],[C_3],[D_4],[E_5],[F_6]) 
) PIV
```

Using Dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @COLSUNPIVOT AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@QUERY  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@COLSPIVOT AS  NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @COLSUNPIVOT = STUFF((SELECT ','+QUOTENAME(C.NAME)
FROM SYS.COLUMNS AS C
WHERE C.OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('REPORT') AND C.NAME <> 'DECK'
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @COLSPIVOT = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(DECK)
FROM REPORT T FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

SET @QUERY 
= 'SELECT HEADER, '+@COLSPIVOT+'
FROM
(
SELECT DECK,HEADER,VALUE FROM REPORT
UNPIVOT
(
  VALUE FOR HEADER IN ('+@COLSUNPIVOT+')
) UNPIV
) SRC
PIVOT
(
SUM(VALUE)
FOR DECK IN ('+@COLSPIVOT+')
) PIV'

EXEC(@QUERY)
```